# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para comparar el valor que tiene una etiqueta con un string?

Tags: javascript

Quería saber cómo puedo hacer para comparar el valor que tiene una etiqueta h1 con id="titulo" que cambiara por unas cadena de texto dentro de un array al hacer click con un botón, con un String.
Va a tener varias validacion por lo cual me gustaria hacerlo de una manera que sea legible y entendible.
Les dejo un [link de codepen](https://lnkd.in/dRAyD2gN) donde lo estoy haciendo.

````
```
<div class="container text-center py-1">
    <h1 id="titulo" class="display-3 py-5">No toques el boton rojo</h1> 
    <button id="boton" class="btn btn-danger p-3">Boton</button>
</div>
````

```
let titulo = document.getElementById("titulo");
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

let fraces = [
  'Dije que no lo presiones',
  'Me cansaste...',
  'Mira! Te lo hice invisible, que vas hacer ahora ?',
  'Te odio.'
];


//Cambiar el titulo al hacer click
boton.onclick = function(){
  next();
}

//Cambiar el titulo

let pos = -1;
function next(){
  pos = pos + 1; 
  let nextFraces = fraces[pos];
  titulo.innerHTML = nextFraces;
 }; 

//Ejecuciones segun el valor del titulo
  
  if( titulo.textContent == 'Mira! Te lo hice invisible, que vas hacer ahora ?'){
    boton.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    boton.style.opacity = "0";
    }else{
    boton.style.opacity = "1";
    boton.style.transition = "all 0s";
    };
```

Comment: Cual es la etiqueta que intentas obtener, cual es el obtivo final en tu cliente, en que linea intentas hacerlo , porfavor define ese tipo de cosas

Comment: Perdon, soy nuevo en esto.
La etiqueta h1 con id="titulo"  y lo quiero comparar en el if, pero al comparar no se ejecuta el código.

Comment: ya te entendi , ya te subo la respuesta

Comment: @Rocks pulsa en [edit] y agrega los detalles _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo que sucede es que el `if` no está en una función, por lo tanto se evalúa una sola vez

Para que puedas evaluarlo cada vez que el texto cambia puedes ponerlo adentro de tu función `next()` de esa forma ya puede comparar el texto de `titulo`

Otra opción es crear otra función para comparar el texto y llamar esa función dentro de `next()`

Puedes utilizar `switch()` dentro de tu función para comparar con varios `string`, puedes aprender más [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

```js
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

let fraces = [
  'Dije que no lo presiones',
  'Me cansaste...',
  'Mira! Te lo hice invisible, que vas hacer ahora ?',
  'Te odio.'
];


//Cambiar el titulo al hacer click
boton.onclick = function(){
  next();
}

//Cambiar el titulo

let pos = -1;
function next(){
  pos = pos + 1; 
  let nextFraces = fraces[pos];
  titulo.innerHTML = nextFraces;
  compara(titulo.textContent)
 }; 

//Ejecuciones segun el valor del titulo

function compara(texto){
    switch(texto){
   case 'Mira! Te lo hice invisible, que vas hacer ahora ?':
    boton.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    boton.style.opacity = "0";
   break;
   default:
    boton.style.opacity = "1";
    boton.style.transition = "all 0s";
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-center py-1">
    <h1 id="titulo" class="display-3 py-5">No toques el boton rojo</h1> 
    <button id="boton" class="btn btn-danger p-3">Boton</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ok, muchas gracias. Pero se puede hacerlo sin meterlo dentro de la funcion next() ? porque mi idea es hacerlo en varias string y esa función se va a volver muy grande. Perdon por preguntar, soy nuevo en esto

Comment: @Rocks, Acabo de editar la respuesta usando una función aparte para compararlo, te recomiendo utilizar `switch()` si aún no sabes como funciona también te puse un URL para que puedas revisar como funciona

Comment: Ah ok , muchas gracias, pero entonces cada vez que quiera comparar con otro string tengo que llamar a esa función ?

Comment: @Rocks, Dentro de la función puedes poner varios `case` con todos los `string` que quieras utilizar, en tu función `next()` automáticamente se envía el texto actual de `titulo` a la función `compara()` y evalúa el `case` que es igual al texto de `titulo`. La otra opción, como comenté es poner el `if` o `case` adentro de tu función `next()` y comparar ahí

Comment: Ah perfecto, muchas gracias enserio por tu tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Como lo estas trabajando cada acción nueva está dentro de tu funcion next() puedes hacerlo ahi como te indicaron o en el momento de hacer click, removi tu if del final y lo meti en el evento click

```
    let titulo = document.getElementById("titulo");
let boton = document.getElementById("boton");

let fraces = [
  'Dije que no lo presiones',
  'Me cansaste...',
  'Mira! Te lo hice invisible, que vas hacer ahora ?',
  'Te odio.'
];


//Cambiar el titulo al hacer click
boton.onclick = function(){
  
  next();
   if( titulo.textContent == 'Mira! Te lo hice invisible, que vas hacer ahora ?'){
    boton.style.transition = "all 0.5s";
    boton.style.opacity = "0";
    }else{
    boton.style.opacity = "1";
    boton.style.transition = "all 0s";
    };
}

//Cambiar el titulo

let pos = -1;
function next(){
  pos = pos + 1; 
  let nextFraces = fraces[pos];
  titulo.innerHTML = nextFraces;
 };
```

Comment: Ok ok, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, entonces todos los if los pondre en el evento click ?

Comment: Si, o despues de este llamas otra funcion que haga las validaciones y las pones ahi, lo importante es quie llames la nueva funcion depues de next

Comment: Perfecto, ahora entiendo todo mejor, muchas gracias por tu tiempo y la respuesta :)

Comment: Si te srivio no olvides marcar como respuesta

Comment: @Rocks, Si te ha servido alguna de las respuestas dadas no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas

Comment: Ok ,perdon soy nuevo aca, muchas gracias por la comprensión xd